# using 1.7.0_51 but Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5

Tags: java, java-7

```
String[] str ={"a", "b","c", "d"};
for (String lists : str)
{
System.out.println(lists);
}
```

in above code while compiling i am getting error like this

```
ERROR in CollectionList.java (at line 19)
for (String lists : str)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5
```

kindly help me out this problem i am using `java 1.7.0_51` version, `OS linux Deepin`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of JDK are you using? it seems that your JRE might be 1.7 but your JDK might be <1.5

Comment: What does your command line look like to compile?

Comment: which ide are you using or do you compile from command line?

Comment: are you on eclipse ? how did you compile it ?

Comment: i am using terminal to compile from linux deepin

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara  i am using jdk version 1.7.0 but i am getting error

Comment: @TedBigham i am using jdk version 1.7.0 but i am getting error

Comment: execute `javac -version`

Comment: do a javac -version and report it.

Comment: @JigaJoshi i get like this Eclipse Java Compiler 0.972_R35x, 3.5.1 release, Copyright IBM Corp 2000, 2009. All rights reserved.

Comment: @TANguyen i get like this Eclipse Java Compiler 0.972_R35x, 3.5.1 release, Copyright IBM Corp 2000, 2009. All rights reserved.

Comment: If that version of java is new enough you can compile with "javac -source 5 YourFile.java".  I can't imagine why it would default to a lower version though.

Comment: @TedBigham Sir after compile using the "javac -source 5 YourFile.java" i got "6 Warnings" after compiled the program i run using "java Filename" it prints the output correctly sir. Thank you

Comment: woo hoo!.  I'm making that an answer!

Comment: @TedBigham Sir can u explain why and what happen now in this problem? then only i can explain to my team..........

Comment: The flag allows new compilers to support (enforce) older versions of the language.  There's also a target version that can be set so code can run on older JDKs.  I'm assuming these are typically used together.  It's just weird that your compiler decided to default to 1.4 or something.

Comment: @TedBigham sir now only i migrate from "windows" to "Linux Deepin" i installed directly the jdk 1.7 only, then how? it will set the default jdk as 1.4...

Comment: You're still using the jdk 1.7 compiler, it just knows how to compile 1.4 code.  Usually you have to ask it to that (using -source 1.4), but for some reason yours is doing that by default.  I chalk it up the weird eclipse version.  I've never seen the Sun jdk do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually set the source version compatibility using -source

```
javac -source 5 YourFile.java
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell javac which version of java you are using. This is done with the -source and -target parameters. If you are using Maven this can be set in your pom.xml with the compiler plug-in if you're using Ant this can be set in the javac Task.

Answer (score 0):

```
javac -source 7 YourFile.java
```

will be the solution for this problem